# How can I make this function print the string in multiple lines (one word in each line) based on the number I specify?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code, I want the output to be printed down in multiple lines not just one.

```
def words(name, num):
    for i in range(num):
        print(name)
        
print("content-type: text/html\n")

words("Max", 2)
```

The output is:

```
Max Max
```

I want

```
Max
Max
```

I'm running this through HTTP.

Comment: @mkrieger1 hes serving the output as a webpage, probably through CGIHTTPServer.

Comment: I do not get "max max", I get "max\nmax" just like the OP wants. I am confused.

Comment: So the question is actually "how to put two strings in separate lines in HTML"?

Comment: Im trying to get the output out in a browser, but i get the word max in the same line. i cant figure out how to make it show up in two or the specified number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

You have to either wrap each word in a HTML paragraph element or put a line break after each word. This is needed because browsers remove simple newlines (`\n`). They need special HTML tags for a line break.
In a pragraph:

```py
def words(name, num):
    for i in range(num):
        print("<p>" + name "</p>")
        
print("content-type: text/html")

words("Max", 2)
```

With linebreak after the word:

```py
def words(name, num):
    for i in range(num):
        print(name + "<br>")
        
print("content-type: text/html\n")

words("Max", 2)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! i did use <br> but not in the right manner before.

Comment: @AL1 please accept the answer that helped you by clicking the grey checkmark on the left of it

Answer (score 1):

The `print` function takes an `end` parameter which can be specified as:

```
print(name, end='<br>')
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
def words(name, num):
    for i in range(num):
        print(name, "\n")
```

Comment: print automatically inserts a newline at the end